# Raw query in express.js route using sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I am very new to using sequelize. I am running a node.js project created using sequelize cli and trying to run a raw query as below within a "put" express route of my application but keep getting and error:

> Sequelize.query is not a function

The query that i am trying to run is

```
UPDATE package_values pk INNER JOIN packages p ON pk.package_id = p.id SET pk.value = true WHERE pk.feature_id = 2 AND (p.based_on = 2 OR pk.package_id = 2)
```

Any help would be much appreciated as to how I can go about getting this query to work with my project.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to include your code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `query` function on an instance of `Sequelize` like this :

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize("logiqua", "root", "", {
  host: "localhost",
  dialect: "mysql",
  logging: function () { },
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000
  },

});

// raw query

sequelize.query("UPDATE package_values pk INNER JOIN packages p ON pk.package_id = p.id SET pk.value = true WHERE pk.feature_id = 2 AND (p.based_on = 2 OR pk.package_id = 2)",
 { type: sequelizeLogista.QueryTypes.UPDATE }).then(()=>{
    console.log("done")
 });
```